# how to bind json data to drop down in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have json array like here

```
$scope.parentChartId = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "chart_name": "pieChart",
    "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "chart_name": "pieChart1",
    "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "chart_name": "pieChart2",
    "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
}]
```

I want show in select-menu(drop down values like)

```
1-pieChart1,
2-pieChart2,
3-pieChart3
```

Is there any way to do it. any one please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles for dropdown (edit)

```
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

you can call like this

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p ng-repeat="child in parentChartId">{{child.id}}-{{child.chart_name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to say something? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. Simply repeat over the list.

That said,  I will suggest you read documentation on [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to get a better picture of what is going on and get the best solution to your problem.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.parentChartId = [
                         {
                           "id": 1,
                           "chart_name": "pieChart",
                           "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         },
                         {
                           "id": 2,
                            "chart_name": "pieChart1",
                            "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         },
                         {
                          "id": 3,
                           "chart_name": "pieChart2",
                           "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         }
                         ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in parentChartId" value="{{item.id}}"> {{item.id + "-" + item.chart_name}}</option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: did you see the link it pointed to ?? You could just have corrected my answer !!

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/nuwanniroshana/pgyj95pd/

**HTML markup**

```
<select ng-options="item as item.id + ' - ' + item.chart_name for item in parentChartId track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

**Angular Implementation**

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope) {

      $scope.parentChartId = [{
        "id": 1,
        "chart_name": "pieChart",
        "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "chart_name": "pieChart1",
        "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "chart_name": "pieChart2",
        "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
      }];
    });

})(window.angular)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select>
<option data-ng-repeat="p in parentChartId" data-ng-value="{{p.id}}" data-ng-bind="p.id + ' - ' + p.chart_name"></option>
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.parentChartId = [
                         {
                           "id": 1,
                           "chart_name": "pieChart",
                           "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         },
                         {
                           "id": 2,
                            "chart_name": "pieChart1",
                            "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         },
                         {
                          "id": 3,
                           "chart_name": "pieChart2",
                           "sub_chart_query_param": "id,part,name"
                         }
                         ]
});
</script>
```